# Stash Login issue in atlassian

Tags: ubuntu, bitbucket-server, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I created skeletal stash plugin project (atlas-create-stash-plugin) and issued the atlas-run command. And during the build stash was deployed into Tomcat. I haven't configured stash yet and I am prompted for login in the first screen. How do I login as there are no configured mail servers.

Installation Environment: Debian - Ubuntu

How do I login to Stash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username/password for all Atlassian products started through the SDK have the same credentials: **admin/admin**. It's buried here:

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Explore+the+Installed+SDK+and+the+atlas+Commands